# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component wehn trying to change data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React, in an app I'm trying to change description and amount and add a note, but every time I try I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ExpenseForm from "./ExpenseForm";
import { editExpense } from "../actions/expenses";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const EditExpensePage = (props) => {

const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
   <div>
    <ExpenseForm 
      expense ={props.expense}
       onSubmit={(expense) => {
        props.dispatch(editExpense(props.expense.id, expense))
          navigate('/')
         }}
       />
      </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const params = useParams()
  return {
     expense: state.expenses.find((expense) => expense.id === params.id)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditExpensePage)
```

Comment: I don't think `mapStateToProps` is a kosher place to use a hook. That's not a function component body. You could consider using the react redux hooks API instead of the `connect` API though, as that's generally preferable. https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Answer (score 0):

As it is saying above, you can use a hook only inside a functional component. In your code you are calling useParams inside mapStateToProps that is not a functional component. I would suggest you not to use mapStateToProps as it is deprecated now and works only with class base components. I suggest you to use new syntax of react-redux that is completely based on hooks. You can learn its documentation here https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to `connect` when the component is already a function component?

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import ExpenseForm from "./ExpenseForm";
import { editExpense } from "../actions/expenses";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const EditExpensePage = (props) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams()
  const expenses = useSelector(state => state.expenses);

  const expense = expenses.find((expense) => expense.id === params.id)

  return (
   <div>
    <ExpenseForm 
      expense={expense}
      onSubmit={(exp) => {
        dispatch(editExpense(expense.id, exp))
        navigate('/')
      }}
     />
   </div>
  )
}


export default EditExpensePage
```